# Augment abstract method in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, abstract-class, command-pattern

I have abstract class `Command` with abstract method "`execute()`". A lot of other commands extend it. Each has its own "`execute()`" implementation.

How can I add some common logic (like logging) each time when any command gets executed?

```
export abstract class Command {
    public abstract execute(...commandParams: any[]): void;
}
```

Comment: `execute()` is abstruct, there is no way you will have a commun behaviour as each class that extends the `Command` class implements its own logic.

Comment: Maybe do something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAYQgFsyEA7AEzgG8BYAKDjbjCghmG2DuRoM2OKF4BXHgEkyYXAAoAdMszlKtAAoIMZFAC5EVAJ4BtALoBKAwDcIASxoBuFuw7ikuO5lEgJPJSpq1DRaOvqGppYMLq7sqlQoELjAirgQAObyAEQ0EHBp6el2VOlw0HCJZMAwABbF6VkWzqyxbLV2KIpimJLAMnIBiqoUwaEIuk0xbAC+LNNwQA) where `execute` is a concrete method which does whatever common logic you need and then calls `executeImpl` which is the abstract method? Subclasses would implement `executeImpl` and not override `execute()`.

Comment: TS doesn't give great ways to force subclasses to abide by this model though.  There are [no `final` methods](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1534) so you can't prevent subclasses from touching `execute()`, and you can't prevent subclasses from exposing `executeImpl()` as `public`.  So you'd want some good documentation I guess.  You *could* make `executeImpl` a constructor argument, but then the [`this` context gets funny](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863), so ‍♂️.  Anyway if this is something you want to hear more about I'll write it up. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz looks interesting. The only concern is to make it clear not to confuse with execute/executeImpl in subclasses by some other developers who is not so familiar with pattern. Could you please write it up as an answer?

Comment: An alternative would be to do the augmentation in the constructor of `Command`, like autobinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to handle this is at the point where you **call** the execute method rather than inside the method itself.

You're not going to get good typechecking on your `execute` function arguments since they are defined as `...commandParams: any[]`.  This is a place where we can make use of generics to enforce that all `Command` types fit a general interface while also not losing information about their unique arguments.

FYI, This could just as well be an `interface` instead of an `abstract class`.

```
interface Command<T extends any[]> {
    execute( ...commandParams: T): void;
    toString(): string;
}

class Executer {
    execute<T extends any[]>( command: Command<T>, ...args: T ) {
        command.execute(...args);
    }
    
    executeAndLog<T extends any[]>( command: Command<T>, ...args: T ) {
        console.log( `executing command ${command.toString()} with arguments:`, ...args );
        command.execute(...args);
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2m4gCYA8AKshAB6T4DOyuAngNoC6AfMgN4CwAUMn6WQgIArpAAUyAHTSEWHPgAKcKHExUAXMiIBKTQDd0wPAG4e-ZGHQBlMFFABzMbuRVbD09wC%20PHggA2cFQ0AKKCIpBQHGb85EKiEMQClHg09MwsErLYuHiaGNn4xCwANFLSyvYaWsjaUbzm-FnyeJKx4RBi0pIVVNoe5t71fNF8bfEAgvgAMuj2ieTJqSCMrJlyOXnrhUQlZd1QlZoktVxDDbIgVOh%20EJJ%20sxIABmNgDshNOcgAJOwf%20JKWGx2ECObSeZAAd2AYAAFrQDsJMBBwBpHqUuj0av0Gnw-i0Xh0MQdeti%20INPEA)

The generic `T` in the `Executer` says that we can pass in any type of `Command`, but that the arguments have to match the expected arguments for that specific command type.

Comment: You mean to add some additional abstraction layer, right? It makes sence.